# Eulers number divided by Pi

Tags: pi

Whether $\pi e$ and $\pi+e$ etc. are irrational or not are famously unsolved problems in math. Is the irrationality of $\frac{e}{\pi}$ or $\frac{\pi}{e}$ equally hard to prove or is it trivial? Haven't found anything about it online.

Comment: See [Wikipedia page on transcendental numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Possible_transcendental_numbers).

Comment: It is unknown whether $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb Q$. If $\frac{\pi}{e}$ were rational, this would not be the case.

Comment: The linear independency has not been proven either. Hence it must be open whether $\frac{\pi}{e}$ is rational.

Comment: BTW if $q=\frac{e}{\pi}$ was proven to be rational, then $e+\pi=(q+1)\pi$ would be proven to be irrational.